# Graph of $XY$ against $Y$

Tags: functions, graphing-functions, linearization

Consider this equation:

$$xy = 4y + 9$$

When we plot a graph of **$xy$ against $y$**, is the vertical intercept a defined value?

My question is because I feel that the vertical intercept should be undefined since when $y = 0$, $xy$ must be equal to $0$ given that any value multiplied by $0$ is $0$. But on my textbook, the graph drawn doesn't indicate so.

Edit: What I mean by plot XY against Y is that the term XY is the vertical axis and Y is the horizontal axis.

Comment: What do you mean by "plot a graph of $xy$ against $y$"? Usually, the term "to plot" is used connected to either functions (we can, for example, plot the function $f$ defined as $f(x)=x^2$) or curves, but the particular phrasing is unknown to me.

Comment: You are trying to create a straight line where there isn't one. Re-arranging your equation you get $y(x-4) = 9$ and $y = \frac{9}{x-4}$. You can now plot y against x which has a vertical asymptote at $x=4$

Comment: What i mean is that we plot this graph with the term XY on the vertical axis and Y on the horizontal axis

Comment: So, replace $xy$ with a single letter, say, $z$, and now you are asking about the graph of $z=4y+9$ where $y$ is laid out on the horizontal axis and $z$ on the vertical. You just graph it as if it were $y=4x+9$. Problem solved.

Comment: @GerryMyerson but the variable z introduced is affected by both x and y

Comment: You're asking us to graph $xy$ against $y$. I'm telling you how to do that. What does it matter that $z$ is "affected" by both $x$ and $y$? It is still the case that if you are given a value of $y$, then you can work out a unique value for $z$. Then, if you want to, you can go a step farther and work out a value for $x$, but that's irrelevant to graphing $z$ against $y$.

Comment: @GerryMyerson So in this case, if y =0 does it mean z =0 since z = xy? So I would think the graph is discontinuous at the vertical intercept?

Comment: As $y\to0$, $z\to9$. You can say the graph is undefined at $y=0$, or you can say it has a removable singularity at $y=0$. "discontinuous" is a word I associate with functions, not graphs, and for a function of, say, $t$ to be discontinuous at $t=a$ it must be defined at $t=a$; $a$ must be in its domain.

Comment: Are we OK now, john?

Comment: Yup, thanks alot! @GerryMyerson

Comment: OK. Maybe you can write up and post an answer, based on what you now know.